# reactjs component getting data from xml with js

Tags: javascript, xml, reactjs

In my react app I have the following component. `props.schedule` is a piece of an xml response. For some reason `map` and `getAttrbute` is not working together so I'm stuck.

component

```
const TimeItem = (props) => {
  const schedule = props.schedule;
  .....

  return (
    ....
  );
}
```

console.log(schedule) returns this:

```
<trip origin="SFIA" destination="FRMT" fare="11.65" origTimeMin="7:47 AM" origTimeDate="07/23/2016 "
    destTimeMin="9:18 AM" destTimeDate="07/23/2016" clipper="4.35" tripTime="">
  <leg order="1" transfercode="N" origin="SFIA" destination="BALB" origTimeMin="7:47 AM" origTimeDate="07/23/2016"
    destTimeMin="8:06 AM" destTimeDate="07/23/2016" line="ROUTE 2" trainHeadStation="PITT" trainIdx="8"/>
  <leg order="2" transfercode="N" origin="BALB" destination="BAYF" origTimeMin="8:13 AM" origTimeDate="07/23/2016"
    destTimeMin="8:54 AM" destTimeDate="07/23/2016" line="ROUTE 12" trainHeadStation="DUBL" trainIdx="8"/>
</trip>
```

I would like to collect all the `line` attrs in the `leg` tags joined by `,`. So in this case I would like to get `"ROUTE 2, ROUTE 12"`. Also would like to know where I should place the function in case of this react component.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need something to parse the xml into a js object. I would recommend xml2js: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js

There are a few others, but they are pretty similar.

Comment: Jordan, I'm a bit confused. I'm also using the `trip` tag attr values and those are working properly with this `schedule.getAttribute("origTimeMin")` in this component. The original xml object contained more trips and I parsed with `DOMParser().parseFromString(responseXML, "text/xml")`. So you think I should parse again the legs which are the children of a single tripe that is already parsed?